# Conditional statement- compare to values store in array

Tags: perl, conditional-statements

Need help figuring out working perl code to put in place of "any of the elements in @array"

```
%hash = (key1 => 'value1',key2 => 'value2',key3 => 'value3',);

@array= ('value3','value4','value6'); 

if ($hash{ 'key1' } ne <<any of the elements in @array>>) {print "YAY!";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) function.  Here's a basic example:

```
print "YAY!" if grep { $hash{'key1'} eq $_ } @array;
```

In a scalar context like this grep will give you the number of matching entries in `@array`.  If that's non-zero, you have a match.

Comment: Caveat: `grep` solution loops through the entire list even if the first element of 1,000,000 long list matches.

Answer (score 5):

CPAN solution: use [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.30/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm)

```
use List::MoreUtils qw{any}; 
print "YAY!" if any { $hash{'key1'} eq $_ } @array;
```

Why use this solution over the alternatives?

- Can't use smart match in Perl before 5.10
- `grep` solution loops through the **entire** list even if the first element of 1,000,000 long list matches. `any` will short-circuit and quit the moment the first match is found, thus it is more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

A 5.10+ solution: Use a [smart-match](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail)!

```
say 'Modern Yay!' unless $hash{$key} ~~ @array;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a hash:

```
@hash{"value3","value4","value6"}=undef;
print "YAY" if exists $hash{key1};
```